# Set multi- "Person" field in list using HTTP request instead of "Create Item" in Power Automate

Tags: flow, power-automate

I'm trying to assign the value of column AssignedTo to multiple people, using data being read from another list with the same. I currently have this working with Create Item action, which requires hard-coding the Site / List name,  and am trying to transition to using a generic HTTP request action to get around this. For all other fields this works fine, but when I try to set AssignedTo, I just can't find the right structure, or any way to inspect the Create Item POST body so that I can compare.

For the Create Item action, I construct an array into a variable such as:

```
[
  {"Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|me@company.com.au"},
  {"Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|other@company.com.au"}
]
```

And that goes into the AssignedTo field in Create Item form, and it just works.

Now I set my new composed body for HTTP request to e.g.

```
{
  "Title": "@{variables('DocumentPath')}:@{items('Each_Stage')['RunOrder']}",
  "AssignedTo": @{variables('Claims')}
}
```

using the exact same array, and the HTTP POST returns: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet`

I believe that for multi-fields in general you need to wrap this into an object such as:

```
  "AssignedTo": {"results": @{variables('Claims')}}
```

So I've tried that but that just gives a different error `A node of type 'StartObject' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the contents of an entity set reference navigation link; however, a 'StartArray' node was expected.` I take that to mean it wants an array directly rather than this "results" object.

I've also tried both combinations but with the key `AssignedToId` instead of `AssignedTo`.

- Array: `'StartObject' node was found ... A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.`
- Object {"results": .. }: `'StartObject' node was found ... A 'StartArray' node was expected.`

What am I missing here? I really want to avoid doing additional lookups of user data if it can be avoided, and clearly the "Claims" data should be authoritative and usable as it is, I just can't find the right way to express it in this request.

Comment: Could you describe the source column structure and destination column structure? Are they both of type **Person**? For MS Flow to work, you need to use **Parse JSON** with schema and then get the claim and then you can assign the value to AssignedTo column. It would be helpful, if you could post a screenshot of your Flow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found part of the issue..
Setting `"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.<ListName>Item"}` fixes the errors, but requires "content-type" header to be set to "application-json;odata=verbose", which I hadn't been doing. Now I have a new issue - the AssignedTo field is just not getting a value, even though the request is accepted and other fields are being populated correctly. Will post as a new question as I see this as a different problem entirely.